# Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite forced to close

Tags: php, android, mysql

**Source of app code** : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

I run the apps on my samsung s2 and android 2.2 emulator, both forced to close after I         login with random username and password. It also force to close after I tried to register.

**logcat(verbose):**

```
02-21 03:09:15.800: W/KeyCharacterMap(563): No keyboard for id 0
02-21 03:09:15.800: W/KeyCharacterMap(563): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-21 03:09:23.480: D/Button(563): Login
02-21 03:09:23.829: E/JSON(563): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
02-21 03:09:23.829: E/JSON(563): <html><head>
02-21 03:09:23.829: E/JSON(563): <title>404 Not Found</title>
02-21 03:09:23.829: E/JSON(563): </head><body>
02-21 03:09:23.829: E/JSON(563): <h1>Not Found</h1>
02-21 03:09:23.829: E/JSON(563): <p>The requested URL /android_login_api/ was not found on this server.</p>
02-21 03:09:23.829: E/JSON(563): </body></html>
02-21 03:09:23.829: E/JSON Parser(563): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-21 03:09:23.829: D/AndroidRuntime(563): Shutting down VM
02-21 03:09:23.829: W/dalvikvm(563): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:65)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-21 03:09:23.849: E/AndroidRuntime(563):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 03:14:23.920: I/Process(563): Sending signal. PID: 563 SIG: 9
02-21 03:49:40.550: W/KeyCharacterMap(600): No keyboard for id 0
02-21 03:49:40.550: W/KeyCharacterMap(600): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-21 03:49:45.180: D/Button(600): Login
02-21 03:49:46.750: E/JSON(600): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
02-21 03:49:46.750: E/JSON(600): <html><head>
02-21 03:49:46.750: E/JSON(600): <title>404 Not Found</title>
02-21 03:49:46.750: E/JSON(600): </head><body>
02-21 03:49:46.750: E/JSON(600): <h1>Not Found</h1>
02-21 03:49:46.750: E/JSON(600): <p>The requested URL /android_login_api/ was not found on this server.</p>
02-21 03:49:46.750: E/JSON(600): </body></html>
02-21 03:49:46.750: E/JSON Parser(600): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-21 03:49:46.750: D/AndroidRuntime(600): Shutting down VM
02-21 03:49:46.760: W/dalvikvm(600): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:65)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-21 03:49:46.760: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 03:49:46.840: D/dalvikvm(600): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3724 objects / 212248 bytes in 76ms
02-21 03:49:52.790: I/Process(600): Sending signal. PID: 600 SIG: 9
02-21 03:51:55.399: W/KeyCharacterMap(748): No keyboard for id 0
02-21 03:51:55.399: W/KeyCharacterMap(748): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-21 03:52:03.429: D/Button(748): Login
02-21 03:52:03.759: E/JSON(748): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
02-21 03:52:03.759: E/JSON(748): <html><head>
02-21 03:52:03.759: E/JSON(748): <title>404 Not Found</title>
02-21 03:52:03.759: E/JSON(748): </head><body>
02-21 03:52:03.759: E/JSON(748): <h1>Not Found</h1>
02-21 03:52:03.759: E/JSON(748): <p>The requested URL /android_login_api/ was not found on this server.</p>
02-21 03:52:03.759: E/JSON(748): </body></html>
02-21 03:52:03.770: E/JSON Parser(748): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-21 03:52:03.770: D/AndroidRuntime(748): Shutting down VM
02-21 03:52:03.770: W/dalvikvm(748): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:65)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-21 03:52:03.779: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 03:52:03.869: D/dalvikvm(748): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3885 objects / 218072 bytes in 88ms
02-21 03:57:03.939: I/Process(748): Sending signal. PID: 748 SIG: 9
```

My database name is android_api, Im using WAMP server just exactly like what androidhive did. Androidhive use below code :

```
private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login_api/";
```

but I use this:

```
private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";
```

and I also try this:

```
private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_api/";
```

I tried 3 URL above but all doesnt work.

I also curious about **config.php**:

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "android_api");
?>
```

Should i leave DB_PASSWORD just like that? because i dont know / dont have the password.

I succesfully run this app http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/ on android 2.2 emulator.

But getting problem with this login and registration app.

This is my first time on developing android project, hope there are expertise could help me to solve this problem. I tried hard to solve this for whole 2 days but nothing.

I checked every single code by many times, but I don't know the causes of the force close.

*Please guide and show me the true.*
*Thanks*

Comment: you're clearly getting a 404.  did you try opening those urls in browser and see if they are really accessible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you kishu27!** You make me focus on the URL and at last I found the solution.

The right URL is `"http://10.0.2.2/android_api/index.php"`

because within the folder of android_api have another folder named as "include" and index.php.
I must connect to index.php first to login and register

Im super happy now !!